# Could we add an "announcement" function to proposals?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, announcements

I recently wanted to post an announcement on my proposal on Area 51, so anyone who enters the proposal can see it. But I didn't find a way to do that; should announcements go in the "discuss this proposal" section? Or as an example question? The type of announcement function I was thinking of was like a closable banner, like the referral one, when you enter the proposal. If this already exists, can someone tell me how to use it, and what type of announcements are allowed?

Comment: What is the purpose of the announcement? If it's to build a community that should have happened before creating the proposal.

Comment: That is one of my questions: "...and what type of announcements are allowed?". My original announcement would be to remind people to not just follow the proposal, also vote up and create questions. But if that is not allowed, then it's just out of curiosity and wanting to develop a better Area 51.

Comment: That seems very general i.e. you'd do that with all proposals, not just one. That kind of thing would go in the area51 general help or FAQ wouldn't it. If you're going to have announcements for proposals shouldn't their contents be specific to the proposal itself?

Answer (score 4):

Back in the old days of Area 51, a feature existed that allowed anyone to add an announcement to a proposal. It looked like a comment on the top of the proposal page.

[image: Example of an announcement displayed on an Area 51 proposal]

Unfortunately, now it's a mod only feature and only those who work at the SE can use it. (A51.SE has no community moderators; the staff moderates it.)

> Or as an example question?

No, the example questions are not for making announcements, and doing this will most likely get it downvoted and closed. That is sure to have the opposite effect of what you want.

See this post on Area 51 Discussions: [Are there guidelines for making proposal announcements?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5688)